# Как сформировать запрос в MSSQL на вывод из нескольких таблиц?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно вывести данные из всех таблиц имеющие вид:

```
very_strong_table_20170109
very_strong_table_20170209
very_strong_table_20170308
very_strong_table_20170407
very_strong_table_20170506
```

Таблица very_strong_table_******** создается каждый месяц (30 дней). Структура у них одинаковая.
Буду рад любым советам, спасибо!

Comment: sql не рассчитан на выборку данных из переменного количества таблиц. лучше всего было бы переделать структуру и держать только одну таблицу и в ней уже колонка даты и прочие данные

Comment: Если это невозможно, тогда разделите задачу на две: 1. получить список таблиц 2. выполнить динамически составленный запрос, с помощью sp_executesql

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, я еще погуглил и все таки наткнулся на логику:
Create procedure in this Below steps you need to follow.

Create table Common_Table with same one structure which all your table like records_2000_02 and others.

Use loop or cursor for all records you get from information_schema which match your table name

Create dynamic sql like ' Insert into your Common_Table select * from ' + Table_name that you get from Information_schema.

Then you get all your data in one table Common_Table

Однако я никогда не работал с процедурами, сможете помочь с этим?

Comment: *я никогда не работал с процедурами, сможете помочь с этим?* Начинайте. Будут проблемы - приходите, поможем (впрочем, задача несложная и сто раз решённая - просто найдите готовую процедуру и разберитесь в ней). А "помогите == напишите мне" - с таким на биржу фриланса...

Comment: Скажите, а зачем каждый месяц создается новая таблица? Пожалуйста, передайте создавшему это чудо человеку вот эту ссылку: [Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно динамически собрать запрос, а потом исполнить его оператором execute.

```
declare @query VARCHAR(max)

select @query = coalesce(@query + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'select * from ' + name
from sys.tables
where name like 'very_strong_table_%' and schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')

execute (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... FROM very_strong_table_20170109 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM very_strong_table_20170209 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM very_strong_table_20170308 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM very_strong_table_20170407 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM very_strong_table_20170506 WHERE ...
```

Список полей и условие отсева везде одинаково.

Такие запросы можно создавать динамически.

Можно раз в месяц при создании таблиц также создавать представление (view) very_strong_table_all вида

```
SELECT * FROM very_strong_table_20170109
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM very_strong_table_20170209
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM very_strong_table_20170308
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM very_strong_table_20170407
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM very_strong_table_20170506
```

и обращаться к представлению вместо таблицы.

Такой запрос и/или представление можно строить автоматически.

Comment: Вариант формально рабочий, но плохо поддерживаемый из-за необходимости вручную корректировать запросы. Посмотрите соседний ответ - там этой проблемы нет.

Comment: Я не говорил о том, что это нужно сделать вручную.

Comment: Также, если иметь таблицу с крайними значениями, попадающими в каждую секцию, то можно строить не полное объединение всех, а только необходимых таблиц.

Comment: Наверное, тогда стоит не просто упомянуть подход с таблицей периодов секционирования - а дописать пример такого запрос. Пока выглядит именно как ручной подход с небольшим намёком на то, как ещё можно сделать.