# Подскажите как вывести из бд название последней таблицы?

Tags: php, mysqli

В бд есть множество таблиц с именами-датами. Например 01102018 или 07102018. Подскажите пожалуйста как составить запрос к бд чтобы вернулось название последней по такой дате таблицы? То есть самой поздней.
Это все что пока имею.

```
    $result = $choosetable->query("SHOW TABLES");
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
    $table = $row[0];
    ?>
```

Спасибо. Не гнобите, я учусь.. ))

Comment: Прям напасть какая с [подобными таблицами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/894530/213987). Вам в сторону SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables для получения списка таблиц, отстортировать через ORDER BY, взять одну запись через LIMIT 0,1. А, и дату пересобрать по кусочкам в формат YYYYMMDD  Обдумайте, могут ли у вас быть таблиы НЕ такого формата, чтобы их отсечь в WHERE. Дальше лучше сами попробуйте, чтобы самому научиться, а не переписывать готовый ответ со стековерфлоу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, таблицы будут создаваться только в нужном формате то есть DDMMYYYY. Я получил список таблиц моей бд через query("SHOW TABLES") и далее цикл. Дальше подумать можно, но так как я совсем новичок мне пока даже не представить как создать функцию для фильтра полученных имен таблиц по дате.

Comment: Впишите код который у вас получился в вопрос (нажмите [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/895429/edit) под вопросом) - дописать код, пусть неправильный, чаще проще, чем с нуля начинать. И, понимаете, у вас вероятнее всего отбор на клиенте делается, в то время как можно выборку оформить только в mysql, а в php останется только вывод данных.

Comment: Сделать запрос для выборки нужных таблиц (либо всех) из бд. Отсортировать по убыванию + вывести одну

Comment: Это я понимаю, код написать не могу ))